# Запуск файла по пути

Tags: java

Всем доброго дня, в моей программе хочу реализовать возможность быстрого запуска определённых программ, тыкнул по кнопочке раз и все программы разом запустились. Вопрос в том, как зная путь к исполняемому файлу запустить его, но при этом не использую никаких консолей, т.к. хочу сохранить кроссплатформенность.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(pathToExecutable);
```

или

```
Process p = new ProcessBuilder(pathToExecutable).start();
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0):

Я бы хотел бы показать ещё один вариант. Этот вариант в отличие от первого 
может запустить например приложение расширения .jar и вообще любое что запускается вот таким вот образом
    Desktop.getDesktop().open(File);